# could not resolve property: funcionario of: br.com.horasExtras.domain.Funcionarios

Tags: java, jsf

Estou trabalhando na autenticação do Usuario, esse é meu código da `AutenticacoaBean`. Quando eu clico no botão entrar da minha tela de autenticação, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> could not resolve property: funcionario of: 
>   br.com.horasExtras.domain.Funcionarios

```
package br.com.horasExtras.bean;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;
import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;

import br.com.horasExtras.dao.FuncionariosDAO;
import br.com.horasExtras.domain.Funcionarios;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AutenticacaoBean {
    private Funcionarios funcionario;

    public Funcionarios getFuncionario() {
        return funcionario;
    }

    public void setFuncionario(Funcionarios funcionario) {
        this.funcionario = funcionario;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void iniciar() {
        funcionario = new Funcionarios();


    }

    public void autenticar() {
        try {
            FuncionariosDAO funcionariosDAO = new FuncionariosDAO();
            Funcionarios funcionariosLogado = 
                    funcionariosDAO.autenticar(funcionario.getMatricula(),funcionario.getSenha());

            if (funcionariosLogado == null){
                Messages.addGlobalError("Matricula ou Senha inválida");
                return;
            }
            Faces.redirect("./templates/Modelo.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
            Messages.addGlobalError(erro.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

esse é o codigo da classe Funcionarios:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Funcionarios extends GenericDomain {
    @Column(length=100,nullable=false)
    private String nmfuncionario;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal salario;

    @Column(length=10,nullable=false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(length=15,nullable=false)
    private String lotacao;

    @Column(length=1,nullable=false)
    private String tipo;

    @Column(length=20,nullable=false)
    private String senha;

    public String getNmfuncionario() {
        return nmfuncionario;
    }

    public void setNmfuncionario(String nmfuncionario) {
        this.nmfuncionario = nmfuncionario;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(BigDecimal salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getLotacao() {
        return lotacao;
    }

    public void setLotacao(String lotacao) {
        this.lotacao = lotacao;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

esse e o xHtml do Funcionarios:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">

<h:form id="formListagem">
    <p:panel header="Funcionários - Listagem">
        <p:dataTable id="tabela" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado."
            paginator="true" value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionarios}" var="funcionarios" rows="10" 
            paginatorPosition="top">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:commandButton value="Novo" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();"
                    actionListener="#{funcionariosBean.novo}" update=":formCadastro:painel" />
                <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();"/>        
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{funcionarios.nmfuncionario}"
                filterBy="#{funcionarios.nmfuncionario}">
                <h:outputText value="#{funcionarios.nmfuncionario}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Matricula" sortBy="#{funcionarios.matricula}"
                filterBy="#{funcionarios.matricula}">
                <h:outputText value="#{funcionarios.matricula}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Lotação" sortBy="#{funcionarios.lotacao}"
                filterBy="#{funcionarios.lotacao}">
                <h:outputText value="#{funcionarios.lotacao}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Opções">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{funcionariosBean.excluir}"
                    update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela">
                    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir o funcionário?"
                        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                <f:attribute name="funcionarioSelecionado" value="#{funcionarios}"/>            
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" actionListener="#{funcionariosBean.editar}"
                    update=":formCadastro:painel" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();">
                   <f:attribute name="funcionarioSelecionado" value="#{funcionarios}"/>         
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog global="true">
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>

<p:dialog header="Funcionários - Cadastro" widgetVar="dialogo"
    draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="false">
    <h:form id="formCadastro">
        <h:panelGrid id="painel" columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
            <p:inputText maxlength="100" size="100"
                value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.nmfuncionario}" 
                required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Nome' é obrigatório"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Matricula:" />
            <p:inputText maxlength="10" size="10"
                value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.matricula}" 
                required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Matricula' é obrigatório"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Lotação:" />
            <p:inputText maxlength="10" size="10"
                value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.lotacao}" 
                required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Lotação' é obrigatório"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Salário:" />
            <p:inputText maxlength="10" size="10"
                value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.salario}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="O campo 'Salário' é obrigatório"
                converterMessage="Informe um valor válido para o campo 'Salário''"
                validatorMessage="Informe um valor entre 0,01 e 99999,99 para o campo 'Salário'">
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.01" maximum="99999.99" />
                <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />
            </p:inputText>  

            <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" />
            <p:password id="senha" maxlength="20" size="20" redisplay="true"
                value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.senha}" 
                required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Senha' é obrigatório"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="tipo" value="Tipo:" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="tipo" value="#{funcionariosBean.funcionario.tipo}"
                required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Tipo' ´obrigatório">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Administrador" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="U" itemLabel="Usuário" />

            </p:selectOneRadio>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar"
                actionListener="#{funcionariosBean.salvar}"
                update=":mensagem :formCadastro:painel :formListagem:tabela" />
                <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Como está o seu XHTML?

Comment: Posta o código da classe Funcionarios é o XHTML.

Comment: Pelo que pude perceber, a sua classe Funcionarios não possui o atributo funcionario, que é exatamente o que a mensagem de erro está dizendo. Quando clicou no botão entrar, provavelmente os valores do formulários foram submetidos e o navegador foi redirecionado para outra página. Poste aqui o XTHML para o qual o navegador foi redirecionado após a autenticação (Acho que não é esse que você postou - ou ele está incompleto, pois ele é um define, então existe um insert em algum lugar).